# What is the best way to make the Yahoo media player autostart, jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Yahoo has a mediaplayer to play media on a web page:

> http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/

but there is no option to make it auto start.

What is the best way to make it autostart, by hacking into the code, or it can also be using jQuery to "click" on one of the media to auto start it, although, how do you know the Yahoo code has finish initializing?  We can use a `setTimeout(function() { // click first one }, 3000)` but it seems too much of a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option for this.
Please check at this page http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/api/#example_usage
If you set `autoplay:true`, the first song will be started automatically..

Comment: Reading the API always helps ^^

Comment: wow... how do you get to that page?  I looked at the original page many times without seeing a link to this page.

Comment: @Jian Lin Mark the Answer correct as it clearly is. This is how SO works.

Comment: Is Kai the same as Ozaki?  You know sometimes in life, when you push, people will not want to do what you push for, because it may be action = reaction, like Newton's 3rd law.

Comment: @Jian Lin, HEYYY !!!  What does "Is Kai the same as Ozaki?" mean..? r u insulting me???? I do NOT know who Ozaki and you are !!!!