# jQuery's click() can trigger event handlers only for DOM 0 and event handlers registered through jQuery...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

**[Update:] This question is related to: what does jQuery's click() do?**

[jQuery's click() is not clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130539/jquerys-click-is-not-clicking)

The following code:

```
  <div id="oneDiv">
    some content
  </div>
  
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="clickme">Click Me</a>
  </p>

        [ ... ]

  onload = function() { 

    $('#clickme').click(function() {
      $('#oneDiv').css({border: '6px dotted #07d'})
    });
    
    document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('oneDiv').style.color = 'green';
    }
    
    document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById('oneDiv').style.background = '#ffc';
    }, false);  // bubbling phase
    
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#clickme').click();
    }, 3000);

  }
```

If you click on the link, then the browser will

1. change border to 6px dotted blue
2. change text inside the div to be green
3. change background of div to offwhite
4. go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

but if you wait and let the setTimeout()'s function to kick in, then it will only do the

```
$('#clickme').click(function() { })  
onclick = function() { ... }
```

it will not do the `addEventListener` one, and it will not follow the link.  (IE 8 won't allow `addEventListener` by the way)

So is it true?  jQuery's `click()`, which is the same as `trigger('click')` will only fire off event handlers registered through itself and the DOM level 0 event handler?

Comment: Presumably (and as partial answer to Michael's answer) some or all of the non-jQuery code is code outside of your control? If that's the case, it may be worth adding that to your question.

Comment: Well Jian Lin have you seen the solution I edited? Can you test it and let some feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is supposed to give you some help for selectors and events, but you mix it with straight javascript. I think it will be better to use jQuery format only so :

_replace

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick
```

by

```
$('#clickme').click(function {...});
```

_ replace

```
addEventListener("click"
```

_ by

```
live("click") or bind("click")
```

(see jQuery documentation for the difference).

_ Finally :

```
document.getElementById('oneDiv').style.background = '#ffc';
```

_ by

```
$('#oneDiv').css('background-color','#ffc');
```

also :

change onload by $(window).load(function() {....});

Tell us after if there is still a problem, but I advise you you read a good tutorial if you really want to get into jQuery and do powerful stuff ;)

Edit : This should definitely works :

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $('#clickme').click(function() {
            $('#oneDiv').css({border: '6px dotted #07d'});
            $('#oneDiv').css('color','green');
            $('#oneDiv').css('background-color','#ffc');})

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#clickme').click();
            }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: What about the solution I provided? You don't seem to care a lot about your own topics....